# Formulário de update não salva

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Tenho um formulário já preenchido com dois inputs extras só pro usuário editar as informações já cadastradas e acrescentar as duas novas.

Porém, embora apareça o `alert` de "salvo com sucesso", quando eu consulto o banco as informações não foram alteradas nem as novas acrescentadas.

Meu formulário:

```
<?php
    require 'strcon.php';
    $query = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT SERVICO FROM pedidos");
    $cliente = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'CLIENTE');
    $servico = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SERVICO');
    $solicitacao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SOLICITACAO');
    $previsao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PREVISAO');
    $valor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'VALOR');
    $acerto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ACERTO');
    $saldo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SALDO');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');
?>

    <!-- formulário -->
    <form method="POST" action="update-edi.php">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="CLIENTE">Cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CLIENTE" name="CLIENTE" value="<?php echo $cliente; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SERVICO">Serviço:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SERVICO" name="SERVICO" value="<?php echo $servico; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SOLICITACAO">Data de solicitação:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SOLICITACAO" name="SOLICITACAO" value="<?php echo $solicitacao; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PREVISAO">Data prevista:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PREVISAO" name="PREVISAO" value="<?php echo $previsao; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="VALOR">Valor:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="VALOR" name="VALOR" value="<?php echo $valor; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ACERTO">Acerto:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ACERTO" name="ACERTO" value="<?php echo $acerto; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SALDO">Saldo:</label>
            <select type="text" class="form-control" id="SALDO" name="SALDO" value="<?php echo $saldo; ?>">
              <option> Selecione... </option>
              <option> Positivo </option>
              <option> Negativo </option>
              <option> Neutro </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Minha página de update:

```
<?php

    $acerto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ACERTO');
    $saldo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SALDO');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sis_tam') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET ACERTO = " '. $acerto . ' ",  SALDO = " '. $saldo . ' "  WHERE ID = " '. $id . ' " ';
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro. " . mysqli_error($strcon));
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
                window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';

    var_dump($acerto, $saldo, $id);

?>
```

Não entendo porque não está salvando, se alguém entender, eu agradeço. :)

Comment: Tem um espaço extra na concatenação, qual o tipo desses campos?

Comment: Ao que tudo indica o alerta sempre vai ser disparado independentemente se houve ou não update. Use o resultado de `mysqli_affected_rows($strcon)` para disparar o alerta em caso afirmativo. Saiba mais em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.affected-rows.php Já, o problema do update me parece que o Roberto de Campos já detectou o erro.

Comment: Na página de update você está recuperando um ID `$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');` que não foi passado pelo formulário.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que não esta sendo encontrado nada no seu `WHERE`, tem que retirar os espaços extras na `query`:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET ACERTO = "'. $acerto . '",  SALDO = "'. $saldo . '"  WHERE ID = "'. $id . '" ';
```

Você estava comparando `5` com `5` por exemplo se o `id` fosse igual a `5`.

Comment: Parece que o problema não era esse. Copiei a sua query mas o problema continua. :/

Comment: Quanto aos espaços o que vai ocorrer é: vai ser inserido nas colunas valores com espaços. Quanto aos espaços na condição WHERE: `a conversão numérica ignora os espaços. Não funcionaria se fossem outros caracteres. Se o campo for char, ai vai dar problema.`

Answer (score 0):

Na página de update você está recuperando um ID `$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');` que não foi passado pelo formulário.

Acrescente na página do formulário um `input` que pode ser hidden ou text ou number:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id">ID:</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="ID" name="ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
      </div>
```

> Quanto aos espaços na declaração `UPDATE` o que vai ocorrer é:

1. Vão ser inseridos nas colunas valores com espaços.
2. Na condição WHERE: a conversão numérica ignora os espaços. Não funcionaria se fossem outros caracteres. Se o campo for char, ai vai dar problema.

> Então, se o ID é numérico a query vai ser realizada com sucesso.